# Best tutorial and info on setting up ASIC Mining USB Block Erupters to join a mining pool?

Tags: mining-pools, asic, miner-configuration

I just got my usb block erupters and I was wondering what is the best tutorial on setting this up to join a mining pool? I'm currently on Windows. I want to be able to mine other alt-coins that uses SHA-256.

Comment: How to set up Block Erupter hardware, how to join a pool, how to mine alt coins, and below you ask how to move coins from pools to wallets. Try searching or asking each question separately if they are not already answered.

Comment: Hi duckxx, could you please mention which usb block erupter it is? E.G. Antminer U1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a decent bitcointalk thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=28402.0

Here's a more direct walkthrough of the installation (for windows 7 at least): http://rdmsnippets.com/tag/install-block-erupter-on-windows-7/ which will likely be helpful.

Comment: doesnt really give info on how to join mining pools after setting up cgminer. mainly looking for a all in one tutorial that shows setup and picking out which mining pool you want to join and how to send the mined btc to a specific wallet.

Answer (score 1):

I use BitMinter and just plugged two (one at a time) block erupters into my laptop, once they were installed properly, I did a port scan in BitMinter and was up and running with no issues, only took but a minute or two.